# REST API for Apple Health Data

Tags: ios, health-monitoring, healthkit, hkhealthstore

Is there any REST API support for health data by Apple? I know healthkit api helps to send and receive data from apple health data store but it is very much restricted to ios apps.

What i am trying to achieve is to utilize the send/receive from any other platform like web / other apps etc.,  Any information / solution appreciated.

Comment: If you want to store & retrieve data, then there is one provider https://www.truevault.com/ you can check. It allows you to store any Health Data with APIs.

Comment: Health data are store on device. A REST API for this service has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen one, but this is a very new service for them. Still my guess is like most Apple services this will likely be restricted to Apple devices.

Comment: Nope.  Still no network API for Apple Health (fitness, activity, etc.) and Apple has essentially stated that there never will be one.  There are also restrictions as to what Health data can be backed up to iCloud.
As of 2018, there is a Health Records API but access  appears to be  limited to partner health organizations. https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/06/apple-opens-health-records-api-to-developers/